# How do Python lists work?

Tags: python, list, reference

I've been using Python fine for a few months, however I became very confused this morning when I read a list question. The answer was talking about "References of lists" when you append a list to another or assign a list to another, and it's confusing me (a lot).

Can someone explain to me how lists / list references work?

Comment: Is this helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9724802/how-does-python-referencing-work

Comment: If you are confused by the basics [the tutorials](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/) are useful

Answer (score 2):

Are you talking about:

```
>>> a = b = []
>>> a.append(2)
>>> print a
[2]
>>> print b
[2]
```

The reason this is so is because they both reference the same object. `id(a) == id(b)` (or `a is b`), and so whatever is added in one is added in the other.

To fix this, you can make a copy of a, which is not the exact same object of `a` but it has the same content:

```
>>> a = []
>>> b = a[:]
>>> a.append(2)
>>> a
[2]
>>> b
[]
```

Answer (score -1):

You can also print a combined list: Not sure if this helps. I would check out the python wiki since they have a more detailed summary of lists and dicts.

```
a = []
b = []
a.append(15)
print(a)
#[15]
b.append(16)
print(b)
#[16]
print(a+b)
#[15, 16]
```