# When do Python variables point directly to memory and when do they point indirectly through another variable?

Tags: python

```
first = 30
second = first
first = 20
print("first: ", first, "second: ", second)
# first:  20 second:  30
```

In the above example, it seems the variable `second` points directly to the memory address for 30, and when `first` is reassigned it therefore has no effect on `second`.

```
class Circle: 
    pi = 3.1419

circle1 = Circle()
circle2 = Circle()
circle2.pi = 10
print(Circle.pi, circle1.pi, circle2.pi)
# 3.1419 3.1419 10

Circle.pi = 40
print(Circle.pi, circle1.pi, circle2.pi)
# 40 40 10
```

In the above example however, when I assign `40` to `Circle.pi`, it has an affect on `circle1.pi` because `circle1.pi` was pointing to `Circle.pi` instead of the memory address for `3.1419`.

Comment: Python's language semantics are not defined in terms of pointers. Pointers are involved in the implementation, but you should not think of variables as pointers.

Comment: You especially shouldn't think of attributes as pointers, because attribute access has way too many fallbacks and customization hooks for that.

Comment: Just edited. Is that better?

Comment: A quibble: `circle1.pi` doesn't point to `Circle.pi`, it **is** `Circle.pi`. As written, `circle1` has no attribute `pi`, so when you attempt to access `circle1.pi`, the lookup defers to the class object. If you write e.g. `circle1.pi = 7` you will add an attribute to `circle1`, but you will not mutate `Circle` itself.

Comment: So `circle1.pi` is `Circle.pi` except when `circle1.pi` is reassigned, it doesn't reassign `Circle.pi` so how can they both be one and the same?  It seems they return the same result initially but otherwise they are not one and the same.

Comment: @ScottyBlades They are "one in the same" in the sense that writing `circle1.pi` when `circle1` has no attribute `pi` (i.e. `circle1.__dict__` doesn't contain an entry for `pi`) is translated to a lookup on the class object (i.e. `Circle.pi`). Essentially, writing `circle1.pi` results in `circle1.__dict__` being checked, and if that fails, `circle1.__class__.__dict__` is checked. If neither contain `pi`, an `AttributeError` is raised.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does Python referencing work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9724802/how-does-python-referencing-work)

Answer (score 3):

Python's semantics in this area can be surprising to people coming from languages with explicit pointers, but the rules are not complicated.

I highly recommend reading Ned Batchelder's [Python Names and Values](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names1.html).

In short, Python associates names with values. An immutable value (like the integer in your first example) can't be changed, so multiple names pointing to it can't affect each other. However:

> If a **mutable** value has more than one name, and the value changes, then all names see the change.

That's what you see in your class-based example. It can also be seen with lists:

```
>>> nums = [1, 2, 3]
>>> a = nums
>>> b = nums
>>> a.append(4)
>>> print(b)
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

EDITED:
From your `class` example:

1. `pi` is a class attribute of `Circle` class.
2. class attributes can be access from the object as you did `circle2.pi`
3. However, class attribute, `pi` is not being modified from your code, `circle2.pi = 10`, it CREATES an instance attribute with the same name, `pi` as the class attribute.

Comment: **Theres NO NEED to _SHOUT_**. Also, it's a little misleading to say that "class attribute cannot be modified from the object". The type object for any given object can always be accessed (and mutated) from `circle1.__class__`. Likewise, if properties, metaclasses, or other niceties are at play, `circle1.pi = 40` could very well mutate the class object itself. I realize these are pedantic points, but especially for questions such as this, its worth being precise.

Comment: @Brian I agree that the phrase can be misleading. Anyhow, none of those thing you mentioned are at play at OP's example. I don't know why you would get offended for bold italic styles, but if you did, I apologize. I'll remove those.