# How is a list appending data when I am assigning it back to empty at the start of each loop iteration

Tags: python, list, loops, dictionary

This block of code pulls in data from an API as a dict and `fields` are a list of the keys we want to find values for. In the function `getTeamData` it passes through the API data creating `teams_list` which is the returned value. The nested for loops are iterating over the dict at each index and storing each value in `temp_list`.

In the nested `for` loop I am appending each value found to create a temporary list in `temp_list`. This is where I am having a disconnect, when the inner loop completes, we then empty `temp_list` but when we then append `temp_list` to `teams_list` we still get the expected results.

The only thing I can think of but still don't quite understand is since we are not deleting the data from `temp_list` and just changing the reference to an empty list, somehow the data is still being held onto by something?

```
import statsapi

# Stores Team data as dict
teams = statsapi.get('teams', {'sportIds': 1})['teams']

# List of keys' values we are trying to retreive 
fields = ['id', 'name', 'abbreviation', 'teamName', 'locationName', 'firstYearOfPlay']


# iterates over the team dict and pulls pre-defined values based on fields list
def getTeamData(dict):
    teams_list = list()
    for i in range(len(dict)):
        print("temp list emptied")
        temp_list = []
        print(temp_list)
        print("adding temp list to teams_list")
        teams_list.append(temp_list)
        print(teams_list)
        for k in range(len(fields)):
            print("adding value to temp list")
            temp_list.append(str(dict[i].get(fields[k])))
            print(temp_list)
        return teams_list


print(getTeamData(teams))
```

Comment: First thing first, is there an indentation problem for the `return` statement? It seems to return at the end of the first `i` loop.

Comment: This was formatting from the browser I over looked, the return is not supposed to be within the loop

Comment: Can you post a sample "teams" dictionary for us to run the function and debug your code?

Comment: I can't see how this would work but note that append() will only add an element to a list. To include a whole list, use extend()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> we then append `temp_list` to `teams_list` we still get the expected
> results.

You still get the expected results because when you append `temp_list` to `teams_list`, you are appending a reference of `temp_list`. Hence, when changes are made to `temp_list`, it is also reflected in `teams_list`. From your code, it seems like you are making changes to `temp_list` in the `for k in range(len(fields)):` loop.

For more info regarding how to workaround this issue (if you need to), checkout [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2612815/8505509) answer. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9724802/how-does-python-referencing-work) answer might also be helpful in understanding references in python.

Answer (score 0):

I have aligned the `return` line, and re-arranged some codes especially `teams_list.append(temp_list)` to the logical position

Will this work?

```
def getTeamData(dic):
    teams_list = []
    for i in range(len(dic)):
        print("temp list emptied")
        temp_list = []
        print(temp_list)
        for k in range(len(fields)):
            print("adding value to temp list")
            temp_list.append(str(dict[i].get(fields[k])))
            print(temp_list)
            print("adding temp list to teams_list")
            teams_list.append(temp_list)
            print(teams_list)
    return teams_list
```